# Clarification needed about Dependency Injection in JavaEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I'm trying to get a clear high-level understanding of classification/architecture/semantic/whatever about the whole dependency injection subsystem in JavaEE, and I'm a bit confused.

I've read many articles, specifications and (portions of) books, and this is what I got:

- **Inversion of Control (IoC)** is a programming practice
- **Dependency injection (DI)** is a pattern that follows IoC (service locator is another example)
- **Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI)** is a Java service that implements DI with some additional features like context scopes etc.
- **Resource injection** via `@Resource` annotation is a (old fashioned? just different?) way to inject resources registered in the JNDI namespace

My questions are:

1. Is any of the previous points wrong in any way?
2. In this "picture", where do `@EBJ`, `@PersistenceUnit`, `@PersistenceContext`... injections collocate themselves? I mean, these are some injection mechanism but they're not resource injection nor CDI... am I right? Do they fall under some specific *umbrella term*, or they've just been added during the years without further classifications?

Comment: EJB = Enterprise Java Beans, @Persistence annotations refers to JPA; are both other specs, always refer to the jsr specification (cdi is jsr 346) to understand the context

Comment: @fantarama I know what EJB and JPA stand for, I'm asking how are these annotation related to the "DI Java ecosystem".

Comment: Since this annotations are defined in other specs, they are not related in anyway to CDI. The full Java EE 7 spec put togheter all of this jsr, so a jee7 implementation must implement all. As i say look on single jsr to see the context and relationships (like EJB transaction propagation to a CDI bean)

Comment: uhm... so you're basically saying that those annotations are just early examples of DI, added without a "bigger DI plan" in mind like CDI did later?

Comment: don't focus on annotations, but on spec, ejb and jpa has different purpose than cdi. If the question is "they use IoC patterns to work?" the answer is yes; EJBs and CDI beans are very close, an EJB is like a "bigger" CDI (but is an ugly definition). I talk about jsr because different jsr define different technology that may be based on others specs. Like jsr 352 define java batch that is based on CDI injection. On the other side JPA is a spec also implemented by Spring Hibernate and you can use it outside a CDI context

Comment: @fantarama Well, it totally makes sense... Why don't you post an answer? I'd be happy to upvote it

Answer (score 1):

@EJB is an Enterprise Java Beans annotation, @Persistence annotations refer to JPA.
Both are defined on different JSR so has differents purpose than CDI, also if both use IoC patterns.

EJB and CDI are tight linked because an EJB is also a CDI bean, but to really learn relationship between JaveEE technologies you must focus on single JSR specs.

For example JPA is a standalone spec also implemented by Spring Hibernate not related to CDI but in JavaEE context you can use an Entity Driven Domain pattern and make JPA entities also CDI beans.